# Android SDK source code is highlighted red

Tags: android, sdk

Hi I have some parts of Android SDK source highlighted red with a message like "Cannot access android.net.Uri.AbstractPart"
And such thing's all over the SDK, but it works fine, so please could somebody explain me is this a problem with my setups or some other

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried syncing gradle?

Comment: @Longi  yeah, it's synced